# How to perform addition in already existing json object in mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, express

I want to add the cost of a particular month for a specific category. This is my object stored in MongoDB :

```
{
  "2022":{
        "January":{
              "Food":30,
              "Traveling":0,
              "Medical":0,   
         },
         "Feburary":{
              "Food":1000,
              "Traveling":0,
              "Medical":50,   
         },
         "March":{
              "Food":100,
              "Traveling":20,
              "Medical":10,   
         }
    }
}
```

Now, I am making a patch request:

```
{
   "month":"March",
   "monthData":[70,45,100]
}
```

Now, I want my data to be updated like this:

```
{
    "2022":{
         "January":{
             "Food":30,
             "Traveling":0,
             "Medical":0,
        },
         "Feburary":{
             "Food":1000,
             "Traveling":0,
             "Medical":50,
        },
         "March":{
             "Food":170,
             "Traveling":65,
             "Medical":110,
       }
   }
}
```

What query should I write using Model.findAndUpate(filter,object) so that above thing works.

Comment: Using dynamic value as field name is generally considered anti-pattern as it introduce unnecessary complexity to query. Consider refactoring your schema.

Answer (score 0):

Your patch request looks to me like this:

```
db.collection.update({},
{
 "$inc": {
    "2022.March.Food": 70,
    "2022.March.Traveling": 45,
    "2022.March.Medical": 100
  }
})
```

[Playgroud](https://mongoplayground.net/p/SxmIYzmKNjN)